# Retries in mocha do not work

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to use [retries](http://mochajs.org/#retry-tests) in mocha. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('chai').assert;

describe('retries', function() {
    it('should not be equal', function () {
        this.retries(10);
        assert.equal(1, 2);
    });
});
```

I'm expecting, that test would be retried 10 times, but it didn't.
Version of mocha is `3.3.0`

Answer (score 3):

Mocha does in fact retry your code. **However, Mocha does not *show* you each individual attempt.** It only reports the final result as to whether the test passed at some point (after some number of tries), or failed (because all the tries failed). If you add `console.log("something")` to your test, you'll see it retries your test as you specified.